# replace all alphanumeric characters tsql

Tags: t-sql, replace

I need to replace all alphanumeric characters with in the input with '`x`'.

```
'12 34 - a'
```

becomes `'xx xx - x`'. I tried to use

```
patindex
```

with `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, but after the first replacement still the same alphanumeric is found. looks that `patindex` works only when removing chars

can someone advice a solution for the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(max) = '12 34 - a'

DECLARE @Keep VARCHAR(50)
SET @Keep = '%[a-vyz0-9]%'

WHILE PATINDEX(@Keep, @t) >0
    Set @t = Stuff(@t, PatIndex(@Keep, @t), 1, 'x')

    SELECT @t
```

Comment: Thanks - it solves the problem. But I prefer not to replace each time the single char but rather chunk of chars